# MIME Types and url_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nice RESTful controller in my Rails application that uses responds_to to distinguish between requests for HTML and CSV requests, serving the HTML if one uses the URL normally, and the CSV if one adds ".csv" to the end of the URL.

In my view layer ERB file, I want to have a link to the CSV. I could just get the URL for the appropriate action normally and then just add ".csv" to the end of it, but that seems kinda hacky. I don't, however, see anthing in the url_for docs that would allow me to do this more cleanly.

Is there something I'm missing, or am I just stuck with something like this?

```
<a href="<%= url_for @topic%>.csv">Download CSV</a>
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url_for @topic, :format => :csv
```

is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Indeed, that appears to do the trick beautifully! Thank you. Is it documented somewhere? I sure don't see it under the url_for docs, and want to be sure I know where to look for stuff like this!

Comment: I like using apidock. users can add comments to the documentation.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

Comment: That isn't working for me. What version of Rails are you using?